# getting POST values on PHP using CURL on C++

Tags: php, c++, curl

Is there someone here tried to post values using PHP and getting the said values on c++ using CURL. I have tried it using codes that i have search on google but the result from the CURL is the html composition of the page.

PHP

```
<html>
<head><title>Test Page</title></head>
<body>
    <form method="post" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];?>">
        <p>Name:</p><input type="text" name="name">
        <input type="submit">
    </form>
    <?php
        if($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"]=="POST")
        {
            $name = $_POST['name'];
            if(empty($name))
                echo "Name is empty";
            else
                echo $name;
        }
    ?>
</body>
```

C++ Code

```
#include <iostream>
#include "json/json.h"
#include <curl/curl.h>
#include <string.h>

using namespace std;

static size_t WriteCallback(void *contents, size_t size, size_t nmemb, void *userp)
{  
     ((string*)userp)->append((char*)contents, size * nmemb);
     return size * nmemb;
}

int main()
{
     CURL *curl;
     CURLcode curl_res;
     string rBuffer;
     string *s = new string("");

     curl_global_init(CURL_GLOBAL_ALL);

     curl = curl_easy_init();
     if(curl)
     {
         curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_URL, "192.168.1.106/testwebserver/index.php");
         curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
         curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, "name=test");
         //curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1L);
         //curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION, WriteCallback);
         //curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_WRITEDATA, s);
         curl_res = curl_easy_perform(curl);
         if (res != CURLE_OK)
             fprintf(stderr, "curl_easy_perform() failed: %s\n",    curl_easy_strerror(curl_res));
         curl_easy_cleanup(curl);
    }
 }
```

I really appreciate the help.

Comment: Everything outside `<?php ... ?>` tags is **always** rendered to the client. This is expected behavior. You should either change the PHP page to render just $name if it sees a POST value, or change the C++ program to print the text between `</form>` and `</body>`

Comment: @Botje do you have an example?

Comment: ... of what? I gave you two approaches.

Comment: @Botje already created a separate php page with the code below, but the thing is since curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, "name=test"); , it only shows "test" when i run the c++ program and when i try to put any character or string on the input on php and submit it, ouput on the c++ stays the same.

Comment: What do you mean by "try to put any character or string on the input on php"? Are you typing something on the program's input stream and do you want to send *that* to the PHP page? Please [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/69450299/edit) so we can see your actual problem.

Comment: @Botje there is an input form on the php and wanted the c++ using curl to get the value on php when the form is submitted.

Comment: What "value" are you trying to get? Please give us a concrete input and output example because the problem is **not clear to me**. Also note that your current code does not actually print anything; you commented out the bits that read the response body or do something with the result.

Comment: @Botje for example i will put "hello world" on the input form and submit it, the c++ program using curl will get the input "hello world" and print it on the console window.

Comment: by "I will put ... on the input form", you mean using your browser (Chrome / Firefox / Edge / ...)? There is no such connection between your browser, the PHP page and a separate Curl client.

Answer (score 0):

You C++ script does fetch the whole PHP response.

That is including `<html> <head> <body>` etc.

If you only want the response of your echo, use this:

```
   <?php
        if($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"]=="POST")
        {
            $name = $_POST['name'];
            if(empty($name))
                echo "Name is empty";
            else
                echo $name;
        }
    ?>
```

or shorter:

```
<?php
  echo isset($_POST['name'])? $_POST['name'] : "Name is empty" ;
?>
```

Comment: already created a separate php page with the code on top, but the thing is since `curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, "name=test");` , it only shows "test" when i run the c++ program and when i try to put any character or string on the input on php and submit it, ouput on the c++ stays the same.

Comment: @BluStack I fear I cannot follow. What do you expect to happen? When you call a PHP script (via webbrowser, or via CURL) the PHP-code returns a bunch of characters, be it only the name in the POST or in case of your example: all the HTML around it, including a form to post. Could you describe what you are trying to achieve?